# Drupal using panels with ajax

Tags: ajax, panels

I have two questions.

I wish to build a website that will use a three column look. I was told to use panels, I found it easy to use.

My question is I have a menu bar, all menus point into different panels, the reason I do this every page I have has different blocks in it, some of these blocks point to sub-panels. (A., is there a "smarter way" of doing this?)

B., my main question how can I use ajax, so when somebody clicks any of the links on my menus only the panels reload, not the full site?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you might have to restructure some of your blocks into mini panels but you could implement this module, [Panels Ajax Tabs](http://drupal.org/project/panels_ajax_tab). Ajax can now be used when loading content via panels, either as a tab or container.

> Provides the ability to have a tabbed panel-pane that displays mini-panels within it.

If you require more control; instead you could utilize Ctools AJAX. Of course this is a much more hands on approach.

Hope this helps,